What cause a situation where I am unable to recover data after SSD failure: Stuck at 31 clusters with unreadable sectors?
I have a relatively new budget 512GB SSD (SATA 3, 2.5") installed in my old HP Pavilion G7 laptop. It was working fine until it became inaccessible, though it is still recognized as an unallocated partition in partition management tools.
I can’t access or recover any data, nor can I repair bad sectors using tools like HDD Regenerator 2024. Disk Sentinel also freezes at a few clusters in the beginning and then marks all other blocks as damaged sectors.
This issue began after an unexpected shutdown of Windows 11 caused by a battery failure, even though the laptop battery can still be charging at the current time. After plugging the AC back in and restarting the laptop, everything seemed fine, but the SSD became unusable when I tried to wake the system from hibernation as usual. None of my partitions, including my Arch Linux installation and GRUB bootloader, are visible.
Here’s a screenshot from HD Tune Pro showing how it reads the blocks:

I’m seeking advice on the following:

What caused this issue?
How can I fix the SSD and potentially recover my data?


Update: The situation has worsened. The SSD is no longer detected in partition management programs and now only shows as "HD0: 0.0 KB" in Bootice.
Update 2: I attached the SSD externally to another device, and it was recognized again as unallocated space. I didn’t format it, but I found that it won’t allow me to alter the MBR either. In HDD Regenerator 2024, it displays a bold red message stating, "Device is Not Ready," and reports 1 reallocated sector. None of the programs can read beyond those initial clusters.
I suspect the issue might be related to high temperatures on my old laptop combined with the budget cooling of the drive. I previously reused an old, heavily-used Samsung SSD in the same device, and while it works fine, HDD Regenerator 2024 also warns me that I need to cool it down and back up the data.

Any further advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Simplest answer? Your drive is failing. At this point it is going to be close to impossible to recovery data without some specialize and extraordinary knowledge on your own part. Depending on the value of the data, you should take the drive to a professional drive recovery service.
I would further guess that the unexpected shutdown you describe may have been due to drive issues, or it could have indeed been a power issue that could have triggered the damage to your "budget" drive. One of the primary and general benefits of more expensive PC components is the ability to handle power fluctuations with less damage. Higher quality conductive and non-conductive components are better able to handle the stresses and resist damage from voltages both higher and lower than expected. Inexpensive components tend to be more sensitive to power fluctuations, and are more likely experience real damage from these.

I experienced a similar data loss with hard drives while using old similar hardware when I just used chkdsk on HDD not SSD back then so I guess you are right in this point. I am in Morocco, how can I send it to a recovery service knowing that is kinda new drive and It didn't pass its life time cycle or ever the warranty cycle?

I cannot make recommendations or give advice regarding trustworthy data recovery services. Generally, important data needs to be backed up. Data that only exists in one place can be too easily lost, and lost irrevocably. Backups and multiple copies is the best way, really the only way.

What is the minimal SSD and PC specs for hardening such data loss? because I don't want to buy another bad SSD or PC.

That question is based on wrong assumptions. Backups are the correct solution, regardless the quality and specs of the storage device. Even huge corporations that spend TOOOONS of money on very high end enterprise class hardware that is rated for FAR more reads and writes than even the good consumer class equipment don't rely on single storage devices: they make backups. Want to be able to trust your data will be there when you need it? Back it up.

I have just discovered that HDD Regenerator 2024 detects high dangerous temperature when I used another SSD on the same device so yeah, It could be as you said my PC who damaged my SSD. The fan is loud and CPU temperature is always at 90-94. I think this was the problem.
